# tomcat jdbc and spring version compatability

Tags: java, spring, tomcat6

I am using **apache-tomcat-6.0.37**,
 **spring 2.5.6** and **tomcat-jdbc-7.0.19**.When configuring **org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource** in xml file, I am getting this error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource].
```

Does spring 2.5.6 does not support tomcat-jdbc-7.0.19?  Do it need higher version of spring? At this current moment I can not shift to higher version.  Do I need to get conform?

Comment: Where are you putting these jars ?

Comment: The jar is in class path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JARs are outdated first of all.

1. Update to the most recent Tomcat JDBC Pool
2. Put that JAR *and* your driver into `$CATALINA_*/lib` and **nowhere** else (`*` == `HOME` or `BASE`)
3. Declare your `DataSource` in your `context.xml`
4. Retrieve that `DataSource` from your `beans.xml` with a JNDI lookup

Tomcat JDBC Pool works flawlessly with Tomcat 6 as long as your run Java 6.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16989485/696632)  is a very similar question.

Answer (score 1):

Right now the error you are getting is Cannot find class, this means that the following class is not in the classpath. You should check if jar is present in classpath or not.

Probable location (Since it doesn't get shipped with tomcat-6.x):

1. WEB-INF/lib directory of war file.

By reading from the documentation, I guess tomcat-jdbc is something introduced in tomcat-7.x not in tomcat-6.x so I doubt if it will work as expected.

Link of interest:
http://people.apache.org/~fhanik/jdbc-pool/jdbc-pool.html

Answer (score 0):

These two stack overflow links will solve your problems.

1. [org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2249697/org-springframework-beans-factory-cannotloadbeanclassexception-cannot-find-clas)
2. [Spring Web App - CannotLoadBeanClassException caused by Java.lang.ClassNotFoundException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4650055/spring-web-app-cannotloadbeanclassexception-caused-by-java-lang-classnotfounde)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved .Though the class path of jar was present in .class file generated by ecclipse .I have forgotten to include in build.xml.So the jar was missing in lib of tomcat.